# Sailsjs cannot set session - TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_data' of undefined

Tags: session, redis, sails.js

I am using sailsjs and redis as session adapter. I have specified that in config/session.js as:

```
   adapter: 'connect-redis'
```

I tried to set the session on login, using

```
req.session.user_data = {
    user_id : userInfo.id,
    role_id : userInfo.role_id.id,
    token   : token
};
```

But I am getting the response like:

```
......./node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_data' of undefined.
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure your sessions are enabled? Because from what I see, your req.session is undefined.

Comment: Yes req.session is available. The error is throwing while setting the data.